# Not Showing Password reset button for certain users in AZURE AD management portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-management-portal

I have created an AZURE Active directory with multiple users.  I am the administrator/owner of that Active directory.  We are creating users and using other features of Azure AD through graphical api. I am managing the users through the azure management portal.

In general when we click on any user through the portal two buttons are displayed at the bottom: "reset password" and "delete".  I am facing the issue that for some users only the delete button is showing.  The reset password button is not showing.  Those users include some global admins and some normal users.

Could someone please explain why this is happening, and what I can do about it?

Comment: Have you tried a web search?  Googling "Azure Active Directory" turns up a fair numebr of informative pages.  I suspect that at this level, you'd find somethign useful there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the engineering team for this feature at Microsoft and I can help you with this.

Can you please let me know if the users for which you do not see the "reset password" button are users synchronized from your on-premises directory?  For these users, we only allow you to reset passwords from the Azure Management portal if you are using our password writeback capability.  This allows you to manage on-premises user passwords from the cloud, but requires that you subscribe to Azure AD Premium and enable the feature when you install Azure AD Connect in your on-premises environment.  You can read more on [how to get an Azure AD Premium trial here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/trial/get-started-active-directory/), and how to [set up password writeback here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-passwords-getting-started/#enable-users-to-reset-or-change-their-ad-passwords).

If for some reason these are not synchronized user accounts, then let me know and I can investigate further as to why you are seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios when you don't see "Reset Password".

1. Users with tag "Sourced from: Another Azure AD"
   you can only reset password in the home Azure AD and not in the Azure AD in which the user is registered under "Users from existing Azure AD".
2. Users which are with tag "Sourced from: Local Active Directory" 
   These users are synced with on-prem active directory. If they are synced with ADFS, "Reset Password" is not enabled for them. It can only be reset from Local Active Directory Domain Controller.
   You can "Deactivate" directory synchronization under "Directory Integration". This will enable "Reset Password"